# typings/node/node.d.ts(259,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DataView'

Tags: typescript

I know there are various issues opened about this, it's just that I don't understand where my problem lies. I suspect there's a version skew somewhere but I don't know where or what the 'best practice' is here.

Here's some code:

converter.ts:

```
/// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts" />

import fs = require('fs');

interface Question {
    number: number;
    text: string;
}

interface Answers {
    ordinal: number;
    text: string;
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs", 
        "outDir": "built/", 
        "sourceMap": true, 
        "target": "es5"
    }, 
    "files": [
        "converter.ts"
    ]
}
```

shell:

```
csvproc> tsc -v
message TS6029: Version 1.5.0-beta

csvproc> tsd -V
>> tsd 0.6.3

csvproc> tsc
typings/node/node.d.ts(259,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DataView'.
typings/node/node.d.ts(273,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
typings/node/node.d.ts(282,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
typings/node/node.d.ts(292,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakMap'.
csvproc>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot find name 'DataView'.

the current node.d.ts on master isn't compatible with TypeScript 1.5

This is being worked on : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3211 < the issue you can follow.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by basarat above, the current node.d.ts isn't compatible.  In the meantime, you can modify your tsd.json to use the sha "7bab855ae33d79e86da1eb6c73a7f7eab2676ddb".  This previous version of the node interface works just fine with 1.5.  After changing the sha in the file, just delete your typings/ directory and run `tsd reinstall -s`.

Comment: How do we set the version in tsd.json?

Comment: You can't set the version, you have to set the sha.  You can replace the value of the "commit" entry for "node/node.d.ts".